# Double summation of an absolutely convergent series in two variables.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

So, there is probably a measure-theoretical proof that if a doubly indexed (unordered) series converges absolutely, then both iterated infinite sums converge absolutely, and are equal, but I'd be fine with a more conceptually elementary proof. I'm trying to show with brute force computation that when a complex power series converges on a disc $D$ with center $z$ and radius $R$ and $w \in D$ then in the largest open disc with center $w$ contained in $D$ (the radius will be $R-|z-w|$) the series with center $w$ also converges (though its radius of convergence can be higher than that) and I need that result about double summation in the last step.

Comment: I think the measure-theoretic "one-liner" you're looking for is an appeal to Fubini's theorem: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fubini%27s_theorem. It's of course possible to give an elementary proof of the convergence with the usual Cauchy criterion for convergence of series.

Comment: See page 112 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/anal1v.pdf for direct proof

Comment: Thank you, I was talking about changing the center of a power series we already know as convergent. If the first center is $a$ with radius of convergence $R$ and the second is $b$ inside the first disk of convergence, I tried to rewrite $(z-a) ^n$ into $((z-b) +(b-a)) ^n$ and expand with the binomial theorem. Then we need to show that the new doubly indexed series converges absolutely, which is easy, and then I got stuck changing the order of summation. But I think my question has been answered, since the series before I changed the order of summation also converges absolutely, they are equal.